# Limit url acces with Django

Tags: python, django

i've an application to manage cars.
each user can add a car and access it, everything is fine but i've a question.
suppose that bob has the car 1 and 3 through mysite.com/cars/1 and mysite.com/cars/3 
marc has the car 2 through mysite.com/cars/2

The problem is bob can read car information with through mysite.com/cars/2 but it's not his, idem with marc and through mysite.com/cars/1 and through mysite.com/cars/3.

How can i restrict access ? via middleware ?

This question can be extended with pieces. A car is composed of pieces. So for example,  bob's car contains mysite.com/pieces/1, mysite.com/pieces/2, mysite.com/ and mysite.com/pieces/3, Marc's car mysite.com/pieces/4
Bob cannot access to mysite.com/pieces/4, marc cannot access to mysite.com/pieces/1 mysite.com/pieces/2 and mysite.com/pieces/3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing about your model and views here but this is a simple way to get you started:

## views.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
def cars(request, car_id):
    ...
    if request.user != car.owner:
        raise PermissionDenied
    ...
```

**UPDATE:** Added the `import` directive

**UPDATE 2:** Added some middleware code still guessing about your views and models.

With middleware the approach should be like this:

## my_app/middleware.py

```
# custom middleware

class CustomMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # get the car param passed to the view (not sure if it is with kwargs or args
        car_id = view_kwargs['car_id']
        car = # retrieve car from the db
        if request.user != car.owner:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

You import this in your `settings.py` adding the full python namespace.

You could take a look at the [docs about middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) and their hooks which is at my point of view extremely simple and well documented.

Hope this helps!

Comment: great. I've to do that for each view i want to "protect" but i looked for a global solution to prevent this solution. this is why middleware seemed to me to be a nice solution :(

Comment: Well, I just tried to provide a very simple solution. If the other views share the same method signatures maybe you may want to create a decorator and wrap them in that.

Comment: @gorjuce I added a simple example of a middleware you may use to accomplish this. Maybe it may help you.

Comment: yep, i've read it and with the documentation i'm reading i think this is what i'll do. i've added more information in the main post, but you don't have to care about, in fact middleware covers the situation.